# Function Component always using previous state in render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm pretty new to using hooks and functional components.

I have a Filtered List. When I try to update the filter, it will use the last filter state instead of the new one. I must be missing some render/state change orders, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

I appreciate any help I can get :)

Pseudo code below:

```
export default function TransferList(props) {
  const [wholeList, setWholeList] = React.useState([]);
  const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = React.useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        value={filter}
        onChange={(e) => {
          // Set filter input
          setFilter(e.target.value);

          // Filter the list
          let filtered = wholeList.filter(
            (item) => item.indexOf(filter) !== -1
          );
          setFilteredList(filtered);
        }}
      />

      <List>
        {filteredList.map((item) => (
          <ListItem>Item: {item}</ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside onChange you should use save the value in a constant, `filter` will not update just after `setFilter(filterValue)` as this is an async operation.

```
<TextField
  value={filter}
  onChange={e => {
    const filterValue = e.target.value;
    // Set filter input
    setFilter(filterValue);

    // Filter the list
    let filtered = wholeList.filter(item => item.indexOf(filterValue) !== -1);
    setFilteredList(filtered);
  }}
/>;
```

Answer (score 1):

State updates are asynchronous and hence the filter state update doesn't reflect immediately afterwords

You must store the new filter values and set the states based on that

```
export default function TransferList(props) {

    const [wholeList, setWholeList] = React.useState([]);
    const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = React.useState([]);
    const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState([]);

    return (
        <>
            <TextField value={filter} onChange={(e) => {
                // Set filter input
                const newFilter = e.target.value;
                setFilter(newFilter)

                // Filter the list
                let filtered = wholeList.filter(item => item.indexOf(newFilter) !== -1)
                setFilteredList(filtered)
            }} />

            <List>
                {filteredList.map(item => <ListItem>Item: {item}</ListItem>)}
            </List>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I had to give the initial filtered list the entire unfiltered list first. For some reason that fixes it.

```
const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = React.useState(props.wholeList);
```

I initially wanted an empty filter to display nothing, but I may have to settle for showing the entire list when the filter is empty

Comment: you always can add condition `<List>
        {filteredList.length && filteredList.map((item) => (
          <ListItem>Item: {item}</ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>`
or set filteredList an initial empty as you did

Answer (score 0):

### Order your code to be increase readability

In clean code

Main changes:

- Use destructuring instead of props
- Out the jsx from the html return to increase readability
- Use includes instead of indexOf
- Add key to the list

  ```
  export default function TransferList({ wholeList }) {

    const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = React.useState(wholeList);
    const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState([]);

    const handleOnChange = ({ target }) => {
      setFilter(target.value);
      const updatedFilteredList = wholeList.filter(item => item.includes(target.value));
      setFilteredList(updatedFilteredList);
    }

    const list = filteredList.map(item => {
      return <ListItem key={item}>Item: {item}</ListItem>
    });

    return (
      <>
        <TextField value={filter} onChange={handleOnChange} />
        <List>{list}</List>
      </>
    );
  }
  ```

and I have a filter component the do the filter list inside.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function FilterInput({ list = [], filterKeys = [], placeholder = 'Search',
  onFilter }) {

  const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState('');

  const updateFilterValue = ev => {
    setFilterValue(ev.target.value);
    const value = ev.target.value.toLowerCase();
    if (!value) onFilter(list);
    else {
      const filteredList = list.filter(item => filterKeys.some(key => item[key].toLowerCase().includes(value)));
      onFilter(filteredList);
    }
  }

  return (
    <input className="filter-input" type="text" placeholder={placeholder}
      value={filterValue} onChange={updateFilterValue} />
  );
}

export default FilterInput;
```

the call from the father component look like this

```
<FilterInput list={countries} filterKeys={['name']} placeholder="Search Country"
          onFilter={filterCountries} />
```

this is in my corona app.. you can look on my Github.

and see how I build the filter

(https://github.com/omergal99/hello-corona)

Comment: That was psuedo code, not actual code, just to explain my problem

Comment: Still, any code and especially if it is famous, it is better to be as clean as possible, because people learn from it too.